# Safely allow users to dynamically select database fields/conditions to search

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, sql-injection

I'm extending a cakePHP 1.3.13 site and my user needs to be able to *practically* generate their own `SELECT` queries on some data via a web app. They were literally querying an MS Access database before but they will now have to use form controls to search via the site, but they are used to and require a degree of flexibility.

They're searching through tickets and there are a couple of `SELECT` fields they don't always need to see and a couple of `WHERE` conditions they don't always need to filter by, and I'm trying to find out how to allow the functionality without adding the security wholes of dynamic SQL.

Here's my find method:

```
$tickets = $this->Hauler->find('all', array(
        'conditions'=>array("ticketDate between'$startDate' and '$endDate'", "LocationID='$plant_id'", 'paid=0'),
        'fields'=>array('LocationID','OrderID','TicketDate','TicketNo','FreightPay','Qty','Total', 'Paid'),
        'order'=>array('TicketDate', 'LocationID','OrderID'),
        ));
```

The only ways I can think to include dynamic fields would either be use `if` statements to select one of a predefined set of all possible combinations of fields (not scalable, annoying) or to create a `$fields` array to append to the `[fields]` key.

The conditions have similar issues and I'm already uncomfortable including string concatenation like `between '$startDate'` but I don't know of a better method there. CakePHP [claims they sanitize for me](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1183/Data-Sanitization) if I use the `find()` method but I'm not sure how well.

**Is there a specific method to allow these "dynamic" searches without risky *actually* dynamic SQL?** I would like to continue to use CakePHP's 'find()' method, I know Stored Procedures allow me to do just this, but this is a case where I want the logic in the code. Also, should I take additional sanitization steps beyond what Cake's `find()` method does in any case?

I only have two very trusted users so security isn't the biggest concern in this *exact* search, but I'd really like to know how to do this sort of find properly.

Update: I've updated my code and solved the `fields` problem as per @Anh Pham's suggestion, but I still can't get optional `conditions` working yet. Here's my new code:

```
        $tickets = $this->Hauler->find('all', array(
        'conditions'=>array('Hauler.ticketDate BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($startDate,$endDate), 'Hauler.LocationID'=>$plant_id, 'Hauler.paid'=>0),
        'order'=>array('TicketDate', 'LocationID','OrderID'),
        ));
```

This generates queries like `WHERE LocationID=''` if LocationID is not submitted via the form, instead of checking for an empty string I would like my query to omit the `LocationID=` portion of the `WHERE` clause if no LocationID is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
$tickets = $this->Hauler->find('all', array(
  'conditions'=>array('Hauler.ticketDate BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($startDate,$endDate), 'Hauler.LocationID'=>$plant_id, 'Hauler.paid'=>0),
  'order'=>array('TicketDate', 'LocationID','OrderID'),
));
```

Users can only see fields that you output, not all fields in the results. `create a $fields array to append to the [fields] key, which is obviously unsafe.` I don't see how it's unsafe.

Cake's find() shields you from SQL injection. So I don't really see a security issue here.

Comment: True about the fields, I generally don't like to pull more fields than I intent to operate on or output though, some of the tables I interact with have dozens of columns, though I thus far only interact with such tables by limited views. Since I know all possible fields they might want, limiting them only at display does make good sense in this case

Comment: you can safely set the $fields array. As long as you use Cake ORM functions, you are safe from SQL injection.

Comment: I tried the `'Hauler.LocationID'=>$plant_id` array style notation for conditions like in your answer, I still get SQL like `AND [Hauler].[LocationID] = ''` if LocationID is omitted in my form however--the value being passed is an empty index of an array, not the literal `''` empty string. Otherwise I have the fields filter figured out from your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your always searching on a text-named field... I sugges pushing the "to search" and "values" as params to a stored proc. Inside of that, you can sanitize and apply whatever rules you need to validate.

Comment: In this case I'd like to stick to CakePHP's `find()` method which I should have specified; sprocs work in this case but I don't want a sproc for every form on the site.